# Can I add and remove a class with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have this link:

```
<a class="btn disabled" id="next" >&gt;&gt;</a>
```

It has two classes "btn" and "disable". Is it possible to remove the "disabled" class and add the "enabled" class to the button? I am guessing it is possible but I have never seen any example of where it is done. I hope someone can suggest something.

Comment: It would have taken less time to search google for 'add class' and 'remove class' than opening new question here. Do it

Comment: This would take less that 10 seconds on google...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm sorry, but I have a hard time believing you can't find examples :)

here:
http://api.jquery.com/addClass/ and http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

Examples given in that page:

```
$("p").addClass("myClass yourClass");

$("p").removeClass("myClass noClass").addClass("yourClass");
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the jQuery [removeClass](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) and [addClass](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) functions:

```
$('#next').removeClass('disabled').addClass('enabled');
```